# C# Clicar e arrastar ou usar o scroll do mouse (PostMessage/SendMessage)

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, console-application

Estou criando uma **aplicação CONSOLE**, preciso rolar uma determinada parte da janela das posições (x=350 y=240) para  (x=350 y=120) (rolagem vertical), tentei de diversas formas mas não consegui. Também não consegui usar a opção WM_MOUSEWHEEL. Segue o código que uso para cliques que funcionam perfeitamente, preciso apenas adaptar ele para clicar e arrastar ou determinar um ponto Y da janela e usar a rolagem do mouse. Por favor, poderiam me ajudar?

```
public class Win32
{
    // The WM_COMMAND message is sent when the user selects a command item from 
    // a menu, when a control sends a notification message to its parent window, 
    // or when an accelerator keystroke is translated.
    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    public const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
    public const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
    public const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205;
    public const int WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 PostMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr WinHandle = User32.FindWindow(null, "My Window");

    Win32.PostMessage((int)WinHandle, Win32.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x00000001, CreateLParam(350, 240));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    /Win32.PostMessage((int)WinHandle, Win32.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x00000000, CreateLParam(350, 120));
    Console.Write("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: please next time serach about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716275/how-do-i-set-the-position-of-the-mouse-cursor-from-a-console-app-in-c

Comment: As an example of the code I posted, I am working in a specific window, taking the Handle from it and triggering the click, I tried to use

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetCursorPos(int hWnd, int X, int Y);

        public static void SetCursorPosition(int hWnd, int x, int y)
        {
            SetCursorPos(hWnd, x, y);
        }
Win32.SetCursorPosition((int)WinHandle, 350, 240);`

unsuccessful, any idea how to work?

Comment: @Integer u can help me? please!

Comment: Alguns controles precisam estar com foco para interpretar as mensagens do windows, senão ele simplesmente descarta a mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem o problema, mas se o que precisa é de algo no qual areas especificas do seu console necessita ter scroll idenpenedente, então talvez tenha um projeto que pode auxilia-lo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este cria alguns componentes que possam ser utilizados em projetos que tem como proposta criação de um aplicação-console:
https://github.com/goblinfactory/konsole

E para criação de scroll independente ele utiliza buffer para que possa emular o comportamento de scroll.

```
public void MoveBufferArea(int sourceLeft, int sourceTop, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetLeft, int targetTop)
{
    int xOffset = targetLeft - sourceLeft;
    int yOffset = targetTop - sourceTop;

    var direction = GetDirection(xOffset, yOffset);

    switch (direction)
    {
        case Direction.Down:
            ScrollDown(-yOffset, sourceLeft, sourceTop, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("No other direction other than scrolling Down is currently supported. Please wait for next major release.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not in a console window that I need to use scroll, it is in a specific application through the handle.

Comment: Não é no aplicatico de console que preciso usar o scroll do mouse, é em uma janela especifica através do Handle.

Comment: Talvez https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335557/3263616 este link te ajude!

Comment: Oque eu devo pesquisar para aprender a fazer essas janelas quadradas/retangulares em aplicativo console?